# How can I do an Inner Join in this scenario?

Tags: sql, database, hive

I have two tables, **agreement_event**, and **event**. 
I have to select columns Podium_delivery_date, Agreement_ID, data_source_type_cd from the table **agreement_event**
and I have to select the columns

RC, Channel, Sub_channel, Event_Start_DTTM,
Event_Subtype_CD, Event_Activity_type_cd, Event_desc, and EmployeeID

from the table **event**.

The logic is Event.event_id = agreement_event.event_id
AND 
Event_Activity_Type_CD = 'UPDATE_ADRESS_PHONE_NUMBER'

My solution is

```
SELECT agreement_event.Podium_delivery_date, agreement_event.Agreement_ID, agreement_event.data_source_type_cd, event.RC, event.Channel, event.Sub_channel, event.Event_Start_DTTM,event.Event_Subtype_CD, event.Event_Activity_type_cd, event.Event_desc,  event.EmployeeID 
FROM agreement_event   
JOIN event  
ON  
event.event_ID = agreement_event.event_ID  
WHERE event_activity_type_cd = 'UPDATE_ADDRESS_PHONE_NUMBER'
```

Is this the correct query for this particular situation?

Comment: Looks fine. Doesn't the query return the expected result?

Comment: I am not sure what I should be getting. I was given a mapping document and was told to write a query for these columns with the given logic.

Comment: Possibly if there are agreeement_events that you want in your result that might have an event record but not of the right type, you might be excluding them with this version.

If you want to include these agreement_event records you'll need to (a) change the join to be a LEFT JOIN and (b) move the type_cd check to be `AND event_activity_type_cd = 'UPDATE_ADDRESS_PHONE_NUMBER'` as part of the join